# Access "sender" without passing argument

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Main` class in which I have a populated array (population now shown in this example) of the `Tomato` object. I want to access a specific `Tomato` and use the `LowerPrice` subroutine without passing a sender object.

```
Public Class Main
   Dim TomatoArray() As Tomato

   Private Sub HaveATomatoSale
      'This is how I want to do my price reduction
      TomatoArray(0).LowerPrice(10)
      'This is NOT how I want to do my price reduction, i.e. including a sender object
      TomatoArray(0).LowerPrice(TomatoArray(0), 10)
   End Sub       
End Class
```

I also have a function inside the `Tomato` class like this:

```
Public Class tomato
   Dim tomato_price As Integer = 15

   Public Property Price As Integer
      Get
         Return tomato_price
      End Get
      Set(value As Integer)
         tomato_price = value
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Sub LowerPrice(ByVal Decrease As Integer)
      'What should I point to here?
      sender.tomato_price -= Decrease
   End Sub
End Class
```

I have searched both SO, MSDN and the rest of the internet for a simple answer to this seemingly simply questions but to no avail (probably due to my lack of a good keyword for this!). How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: `LowerPrice` is a method which will lower the price of ***the*** tomato object it is invoked on.  In the top code, `TomatoArray(0)` (only)

Comment: @Plutonix correct, but how can I access that object without passing a sender argument to my subroutine?

Comment: `TomatoArray(0)` is that object.  no need to pass it, you are invoking a method on that object.  `tomato_price -= Decrease` is all you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is `Me`:

```
Public Sub LowerPrice(ByVal Decrease As Integer)
    Me.tomato_price -= Decrease
End Sub
```

Note that `Me` is optional, so the following would work as well:

```
Public Sub LowerPrice(ByVal Decrease As Integer)
    tomato_price -= Decrease
End Sub
```

In fact, you might want to take advantage of *automatic properties* and reduce your code to:

```
Public Class tomato
   Public Property Price As Integer = 15

   Public Sub LowerPrice(ByVal decreaseBy As Integer)
      Me.Price -= decreaseBy
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I thought 'Me' was always in reference to the main class, but this works well and is the answer to my question. Further, thanks for the explaination on automatic properties, this will no doubt reduce the amount of code in my program. Thank you very much!